# JavaScript editor w/easy function navigation and "code hinting"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, dreamweaver

I'm currently working on my Google Chrome extension that requires writing some extensive JavaScript code. This involves navigation/jumping between functions in the JS project.

I've been first using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 to write my JS code. And although it has somewhat OK code hinting, it does not have a way for me to jump between functions.

I then tried opening JS files in my Visual Studio 2013. It has an even better code hinting (or Intellisense) but it doesn't have a way to jump between JS functions either.

The following is a screenshot from the Visual Studio for a C++ project that will explain what I mean by "jumping beween functions":

[image]

As you can see it has a nice dropdown menu that lets me jump from function to function.

Also the code hinting, or Intellisense would be nice. It's when you type JS code and then, say, hit "." and the popup window gives you an option of the object's possible properties. Something like this (again for a C++ project):

[image]

So I was curious if there's a JavaScript editor like that?

PS. I'm currently working on Windows, but Mac would be fine too.

Comment: Well, since IntelliSense is a Microsoft implementation, so that would be .. VS. (The [ReSharper extension, at least from 6, does have some *autocomplete*-filtering support](http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/), but it can only guess so much from the lack-of-types-in-context.)

Comment: Hmm, I ran into [Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/) (also from Jetbrains) while trying to pin down some specific ReSharper notes .. never used it. But ReSharper alone does have *significantly* better navigation-to-source than stock VS (in JS and elsewhere). Sublime2 also supports pretty good navigation, but limited autocomplete.

Comment: @user2864740: Please don't catch me semantics. I'm not asking for MS only solution. As for Webstorm, that looks promising. I'll need to try it. Thanks.

Comment: @user2864740: I was able to download the test version of webstorm over the weekend. I can't seem to find how to jump between functions in a js file. Am I missing something?

Comment: I downloaded it over the weekend as well and played with it for about an hour. I am using the VS key bindings and F12 navigates-to-definition (same as Navigate -> Declaration from the menu). If there is an ambiguous definition (the heuristics seem to be limited, not sure how/if it also applies any structural typing filters) then a list is brought up. All the source definitions I've tried to reference have been within the scope of the "opened directory" or subdirectory thereof.

Comment: @user2864740: What I was asking about is an alphabetized listing of all methods in one js file, and a capability to jump to a method that I want. Where does it do that?

Comment: I just uninstalled that Webstorm. It's pretty **worthless & slow** too. It doesn't do anything that Dreamweaver or Visual Studio don't. So I'm still looking...

Comment: No need to shout, although I wasn't impressed by it either - if working in VS (which is where I live when not in Sublime [and Sublime does also support limited navigation/autocomplete]), try out ReSharper (also from Jetbrains but it leverages VS instead of being a separate [sluggish] application; it does like RAM to to make it happy with project-wide inspections though). ReSharper also supports navigation and outlining (adding onto VS such that I am not sure what provides what anymore), including in JavaScript. Same general limitations though .. damn dynamically-typed languages.

Answer (score 3):

Have to answer my own question. I did some research and this plug-in for Visual Studio is exactly what I was looking for:

[Javascript Parser](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/288a2b0f-1357-47b4-8215-1134c36bdf30)

It comes with the following features:

- It displays function names & global variables in a tree-like control in a dockable VS pane.
- It allows to quickly navigate from one JS function to another by simply clicking their names in the list.
- It automatically highlights the function in the list that I'm currently in (in the code pane.)
- It is quite robust unlike anything else I tried.
- It installed without issues on VS 2010 and VS 2013 (that I had.)
- And most of all, it's free.

PS. Now the question is what shall I do on my Mac...